# Spring cloud Zuul reverse proxy routing not working with versioned and context path specified rest application

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

Created a spring boot application and sets context path and version. Then added configurations for zuul proxy for routing. Me refer the spring example [Routing and Filtering](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/). Only difference in application.properties is added contextPath and version. Also enabled zuul proxy using **@EnableZuulProxy** annotation. But the routing is not working. When I remove the version and context it works.

application.properties file

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/app1
version=v1
zuul.routes.foos.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.foos.url=http://localhost:8081/app2/v1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. Forgot to add version in zuul path. Need to add **version** also in zuul path.

application.properties

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/app1
version=v1
zuul.routes.foos.path=/v1/api/**
zuul.routes.foos.url=http://localhost:8081/app2/v1/
```